# Unable to open dropdown present at bottom of screen

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2016

1. We have migrated from SSRS version 2008 to 2016.
2. We have a report having multiple parameters such that the parameters pane exceeds the laptop screen dimension.
3. Due to which the multi-value drop-down parameter present at bottom of screen is not opening as it does not have the space to open it.
4. In previous version, we used to click the "small upward arrow" present at bottom middle of screen and the screen used to expand.
5. But this is not happening in new version. Please suggest how this bottom drop-down can be viewed.
6. Also, changing the position of drop-down is not an option as there is forward dependency.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you hit `F11` to make the browser go full screen mode? See if this helps to view the dropdown list.

Comment: I might be wrong but the parameters layout is different in SSRS 2016. I "think" you can re-order parameters within the parameter position grid as long as within the RDL they are in the correct order (like they had to be in SSRS2008). I can' test this at the moment but worth a look.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
@WEI_DBA - F11 is not helping as I am already working on full screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
@AlanSchofield - Order of parameters is same. Just that in previous version, clicking this "upward arrow" twice helped in increasing the screen size.
But this is not happening in new version.